# Facebook API "conversations" webhook

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-webhooks

I'm developing a bot that receives a call from "conversations webhook" to know when a page receives a new message and answer it from my bot.

I've tried "messages" but I can not even make it activate when they send me a message.

I have my conversations webhook active. The "conversations" callback is something like this:

```
{"entry":[{"changes":[{"field":"conversations","value":{"thread_id":"t_100006208XXXXXX","page_id":309151156XXXXXX,"thread_key":"t_100006208XXXXXX"}}],"id":"309151156XXXXXX","time":1510581746}],"object":"page"}
```

The problem is that the webhook always sends the same thread_id and thread_key. The page_id does change, but I can not find the way to know which conversation is the one that varies.

Thank you!

Comment: Why are you not using chatbot web hook directly?

Comment: Because it is not only for 1 web page, it is for many. What it does is work as a "proxy" between api.ai and my clients' sites

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it! The problem was that I made the call to the api with an access_token from my app, and not from the site itself.

Comment: It is now depreciated replace it with messages webhook.